# getting first div contents using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using following code to get columns of rows:

```
$.each( items, function(i, item){
     columns = $(item).children();
     //columns[5]
     //columns[7]
});
```

now each column has a div. I want to get inner contents of div. I tried to use `columns[5]` and it gave div like this

```
<div style= "" > 123 </div>
```

I need 123 only

Comment: [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)?

Comment: Use the `.html` method - `columns.eq(5).html()`.

Comment: but html will return whole div, i need div inner html . column 5 is like this <td> <div =style""> 123 </div> </td>

Comment: `columns[5].innerHtml` or `columns.eq(5).text()` should do.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: have any of the answers helped you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for this.

```
$.each( items, function(i, item){
     columns = $(item).children();
     alert($(columns[5].text())); // create jQuery object and get text from that
});
```

Comment: Nope! `columns[5]` will return the DOM object, which does not have the `.text()` method.

Comment: Your code results in error, DOM element object has no `text` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
columns.eq(5).find("div:first").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `columns` is a jQuery collection you can use [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery object referencing the DOM element in the specified index. As it is a jQuery object which is returned by `eq()` you can call jQuery's [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method on it.

```
$.each( items, function(i, item){
    columns = $(item).children();
    columns.eq(5).text();
});
```

Alternatively you can get the actual DOM element from the jQuery collection at the specified index and call [**innerHtml**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) directly:

```
$.each( items, function(i, item){
    columns = $(item).children();
    columns[5].innerHtml;
});
```